# Django Debug Toolbar panel click error, undefined

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I am using Django 1.3.1, and successfully installed Django Debug Toolbar 0.9.4. When I open my page, I see panel on topright corner, I can open or close it, but when I try to click any of panel (SQL, Time, Templates etc.) details appear for 0.5 seconds and then panel hides and dont appear again, before I refresh page myself. In chromium console I see:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/razvivayushie-igrushki/c8/undefined 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Actual url is http: //localhost:8000/razvivayushie-igrushki/c8/, undefined appends after click  on any panel.

I successfully installed debug toolbar before, on many projects, but this error comes for the first time, and I dont know how to fix it. I tried to disable all scripts on page, but that didnt help. Also there are no errors on page.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I found out the solution. I had installed extension in chromium, mine was called VkButton, and it was conflicting. So disabling it solved my problem!

Comment: it's perfectly ok on SO to make this an "answer" and accept it (also helps others see this question is no longer in need for an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution. I had installed extension in chromium, mine was called VkButton, and it was conflicting. So disabling it solved my problem